# C# - Unexpected authentication method mysql_native_password exception

Tags: c#, mysql, exception, connection

I didn't see anything on this, but I've been trying for the longest time to get some practice with an SQL database. I tried MSSQL and was frustrated to no end, so I tried MySQL and got a bit further. The database seems to be up and running, and I even did a query to make a table. Although when trying to connect with Microsoft's C# Express edition I get the exception: "unexpected authentication method mysql_native_password" I know the password is correct. I'm even referencing MySQL.Data.dll. Here's my code, I get the exception on connection.Open().Can someone please help me out?

```
     public Form1()
     {
      MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("Data Source = localhost;          Initial Catalog = MySQL55; Integrated Security = SSPI; User ID = root; Password = <REMOVED>;");

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (connection != null)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What provider are you using?
If you are using MySQL Connecter .net, then you connection string should be something like...

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

If you are using eInfoDesigns provider, then...

```
Data Source=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Command Logging=false;
```

If SevenObjects

```
Host=myServerAddress;UserName=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Database=myDataBase;
```

if Devart

```
User ID=root;Password=myPassword;Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=myDataBase; Direct=true;Protocol=TCP;Compress=false;Pooling=true;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connection Lifetime=0;
```

if MySQLDriverCS

```
Location=myServerAddress;Data Source=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Port=3306;Extended Properties="""";
```

if MySql OLEDB

```
Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=mydb;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

if .Net OLEDB

```
Provider=MySQLProv;Data Source=mydb;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;
```

if MySQl Connector

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.5 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=myDataBase; User=myUsername;Password=myPassword;Option=3;
```

More help can be found here http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql

It is actually much easier to use SQL Server as it is built in and VS is designed to work with it.

Comment: This sort of helped, but now I'm getting an unknown database error.