# Connect to MySQL DB using ASP.NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have my connection string set as

```
<add name="myconn" connectionString="server=192.X.Y.Z;user id=myusername;persistsecurityinfo=False;database=mydatabasehere;port=3306;Password=mypassword;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

and later this error appear:

> An exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred
>   in MySql.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Authentication to host '192.X.Y.Z' for
>   user 'myusername' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with
>   message: Access denied for user
>   'myusername'@'crlspr-myipaddresshere.myacc.net' (using password: NO)

What will be the problem of this exception? 
my connection seems to be ok since I just tested from **MySQL Workbench** as well in **Visual Studio * Server Explorer**

Why the error message get my ipaddress, 'myusername'@'crlspr-myipaddresshere.myacc.net'? maybe is a firewall problem.

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10096698/188331 ?

Comment: no. I try a couple of those and I find similar result or keyword not supported. But thanks you, because I am now sure is the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Since my problem was the DB connection string and I was not sure which one  [@Raptoy suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10096698/188331) will work or not, Then I went to MySQL website and get one of their example
[4.14.2 Usage: Creating A New MVC Web Application](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-visual-studio-mvc-project-wizard-usage.html)
and the connection string that was generated by the wizard finally works:

```
<add name="myconn" connectionString="server=192.X.Y.Z;user id=myusername;password=mypassword;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=mydatabasehere" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

You will notice the connection string contains:

- server
- user id
- password
- persistsecurityinfo=True
- database